# Tkinter windows automatically postioning

Tags: python, tkinter

I've had some trouble with positioning windows front-to-back in Tkinter. I've added a file upload system that works fine, except it causes my "Home" window to move in front of my "Create" one. I know that I can use the `lift()` function, but I can't put it anywhere that works. I've tried re-ordering the functions/classes, but nothing seems to be working. I'm fairly new to Python, so I don't know of any easy solution to this.
Here's my code:

```
import tkinter
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfile
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
import sys

def uploadreq():
    global img
    ftypes = [(".JPG Files", "*.jpg"), (".PNG Files", "*.png")]
    filename = filedialog.askopenfilename(filetypes = ftypes)
    img = Image.open(filename)
    width, height = img.size
    if width > 1500 or height > 800:
        rimg = img.resize((width/2, height/2))
        img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(rimg)
        imglabel = Label(home, image = img)
        imglabel.pack()
    elif width > 3000 or height > 1800:
        tk.messagebox.askokcancel("Error", "Image too large. Please select a file under 3000x1600 px.")
    else:
        imglabel = Label(home, image = img)
        imglabel.pack()

def quit(win):
    win.destroy
    sys.exit()
        
class Home(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, title=title, subt=subt):
        super().__init__()
        self.geometry("1920x1080")
        self.attributes("-fullscreen", True)
        self.title("Home")
        title = Label(self, text="Title", font=(title), height=2, pady=5)
        desc = Label(self, text="Subtitle", font=(subt), wraplength=500, justify="center", pady=5)
        title.pack()
        desc.pack()
        Button(self, text = "Create +", font=subt, bd=0, command=create).place(x=1700,y=50)
        Button(self, bd = 0, text = "x", font = subt, fg = "white", bg = "red", command=lambda:quit(self)).place(x=1890,y=0)

class createp(Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.geometry("1920x1080")
        self.attributes("-fullscreen", True)
        self.title("Create")
        Button(self, text="Upload file", font=subt, pady=5, bd=0, command=uploadreq).pack()
        Button(self, bd = 0, text = "x", font = subt, fg = "white", bg = "red", command=lambda:quit(self)).place(x=1890,y=0)

def create():
    global create 
    create = createp()

if __name__ == "__main__":

    home = Home()
    home.mainloop()
```

Comment: It is not clear what your issue is.  Do you mean that the *home* window is raised when the `askopenfilename` dialog is open?  If yes, pass `parent=create` to `askopenfilename(...)`.  Note also that you should not overwrite `create()` inside that function, either rename `create()` or use another variable name inside that function.

Comment: @acw1668 Thanks, it worked, but now it's giving me the error "image "<PIL.PngImagePlugin.PngImageFile image mode=RGBA size=48x48 at (ns if i can post this)>" doesn't exist"

Comment: Because you used instance of `Image` in the `else` block.